# Bash adds extra space between characters

Tags: bash, command-line

On one particular directory, bash is adding an extra tab worth of space between cursor points/characters that I type.

For example:

```
~(master)$              l                 s
```

If I am still typing once it reaches the end of that line, rather than creating a new line as expected, the characters that I type appear to overwrite each other in the last space on the line.  If I hit return(enter) the command will execute as it normally would.

This is ONLY occurring on one particular directory.. In other directories, bash operates as usual.

So far this has occurred over a two day period.  In that time I have restarted bash, my computer, worked in other directories with no issues.

```
declare -p git_branch git_dirty
```

outputs:

```
declare -- git_branch="(master)" declare -- git_dirty="*"
```

---

```
type find_git_branch find_git_dirty update_terminal_cwd
```

outputs:

```
find_git_branch is a function
find_git_branch () 
{ 
local branch;
if branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null); then
    if [[ "$branch" == "HEAD" ]]; then
        branch='detached*';
    fi;
    git_branch="($branch)";
else
    git_branch="";
fi
}
find_git_dirty is a function
find_git_dirty () 
{ 
local status=$(git status --porcelain 2> /dev/null);
if [[ "$status" != "" ]]; then
    git_dirty='*';
else
    git_dirty='';
fi
}
update_terminal_cwd is a function
update_terminal_cwd () 
{ 
local SEARCH=' ';
local REPLACE='%20';
local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}";
printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
}
```

Bash debug outputs:

```
+ w
12:46  up 21:23, 3 users, load averages: 1.40 1.69 1.69
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
holiday  console  -                Mon15   21:22 -
holiday  s000     -                11:13      53 grunt                                                                     
holiday  s001     -                11:53       - w
```

Comment: It repeats in that directory? You `cd` into that directory and the problem happens. You `cd` out and it stops. You `cd` in again and it starts again? What is the directory name? What does `declare -p PS1 PROMPT_COMMAND` output?

Comment: Correct.. It repeats in that directory, all others are normal.  This is the output:   declare -x PS1="\\u@\\h \\w \\[\\]\$git_branch\\[\\]\$git_dirty\\[\\]\$ "
declare -- PROMPT_COMMAND="find_git_branch; find_git_dirty; update_terminal_cwd; "

Comment: What is the name of that directory?

Comment: It is a theme I'm building for Wordpress.. filepath is wp-content/themes/CustomTheme

Comment: Try saving your PS1 and PROMPT_COMMAND somewhere and then setting them to blank and try it again.

Comment: What does `declare -p git_branch git_dirty` output in that directory? What does `type find_git_branch find_git_dirty update_terminal_cwd` output (it should be the code for those functions)?

Comment: Update the post with the code snippets instead of posting a comment.

Comment: Did you tried to debug it with `bash -x`/`set -x`?

Comment: Other than using it for Git purposes, I am bash illiterate.  I ran the debug command but I'm not sure what I'm looking for.  Will post results above.